# Vista networking problem?

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking

Here is a problem at my home network. We have two laptops in our household both Vistas. I can not access internet via my Cisco Wireless Router when both laptops are switched on. However I can be connected to Wireless network via one of my laptop and my phone.

Is this a networking issue or Vista issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check the IP addresses of both machines when they are connected via the wireless.

Some questions to answer:

1. Are both machines getting IP addresses?
2. Are both machines getting the same IP address?
3. Is the same machine always able to connect and the other one not?

If 1 is false or 2 is true, then you have a networking issue. If 3 is true, then there may be an issue with that specific machine.

There are 1000 reasons why a machine can't connect to a wifi connection. The hardware could be too old to support a specific security protocol, hardware could fail, etc.

Leave a comment if you notice anything strange with investigating these questions and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a question: (assuming you're on broadband) are you using DSL or cable? Also, what kind of modem are you using (brand and model)?

There are some broadband modems (have seen this with DSL providers more than cable providers) that also have routing functionality (esp. the Netopia DSL modems).

If you have one of the modem/routers, you have to change settings in the router that has everything connected to it so it functions as a bridge. How to do that depends on the router and good luck to you.